# How to collect / make new array by existing arrays label wise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to create new array from slicing the existing array by it's key?

for example my input is :

```
var array = [{"one":"1"},{"one":"01"},{"one":"001"},{"one":"0001"},{"one":"00001"},
{"two":"2"},{"two":"02"},{"two":"002"},{"two":"0002"},{"two":"00002"},
{"three":"3"},{"three":"03"},{"three":"003"},{"three":"0003"},{"three":"00003"},
{"four":"4"},{"four":"04"},{"four":"004"},{"four":"0004"},{"four":"00004"},
{"five":"5"},{"five":"05"},{"five":"005"},{"five":"0005"},{"five":"00005"} ];
```

my output should be :

```
var outPutArray = [
    {"one" : ["1","01","001","0001","00001"]},
    {"two":["2","02","002","0002","00002"]},
    {"three":["3","03","003","0003","00003"]},
    {"four":["4","04","004","0004","00004"]},
    {"five":["5","05","005","0005","00005"]}
]
```

is there any short and easy way to achieve this in `javascript`?

Comment: This can be done with a relatively straightforward loop. Please show some effort. At the moment this is a 'write my code for me' request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create array and then use `forEach()` loop to add to that array and use `thisArg` param to check if object with same key already exists.

```js
var array = [{"one":"1","abc":"xyz"},{"one":"01"},{"one":"001"},{"one":"0001"},{"one":"00001"},{"two":"2"},{"two":"02"},{"two":"002"},{"two":"0002"},{"two":"00002"},{"three":"3"},{"three":"03"},{"three":"003"},{"three":"0003"},{"three":"00003"},{"four":"4"},{"four":"04"},{"four":"004"},{"four":"0004"},{"four":"00004"},{"five":"5"},{"five":"05"},{"five":"005"},{"five":"0005"},{"five":"00005","abc":"xya"} ];

var result = [];
array.forEach(function(e) {
  var that = this;

  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(key) {
    if(!that[key]) that[key] = {[key]: []}, result.push(that[key])
    that[key][key].push(e[key])
  })
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works, but when I add, additional property, it fails. here if the d0emo : https://jsfiddle.net/b8pwdrgr/ - i have added `abc` in first and last array

Comment: What is desired result in that case?

Comment: I need to create new array with `new label` with 2 properties. basically the `key` is dynamic create dynamic array

Comment: Please update your question and provide desired result in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var outputArray=[array.reduce((obj,el)=>(Object.keys(el).forEach(key=>(obj[key]=obj[key]||[]).push(el[key])),obj),{})];
```

Reduce the Array to an Object,trough putting each Arrays object key to the Object as an Array that contains the value.

http://jsbin.com/leluyaseso/edit?console

Comment: Not able to understand, is it pure javascript?